# How to save a jupyter notebook without local kernel information

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, version-control, anaconda

I'm contributing to a project on GitHub which contains jupyter notebooks.  When I edit and run one of the existing notebooks on my local machine and then submit a pull request it fails one of the tests with the following error message:

```
...
  File "/usr/share/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 114, in kernel_spec
    self._kernel_spec = self.kernel_spec_manager.get_kernel_spec(self.kernel_name)
  File "/usr/share/miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_client/kernelspec.py", line 230, in get_kernel_spec
    raise NoSuchKernel(kernel_name)
jupyter_client.kernelspec.NoSuchKernel: No such kernel named conda-env-control-dev-py
```

Note that `control-dev` is the name of the local conda environment I am using to develop and test the code and so `conda-env-control-dev-py` is presumably the local kernel name.

One solution is to go into the notebook raw text file and change the following lines manually:

```
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python [conda env:control-dev]",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "conda-env-control-dev-py"
  },
```

If I change the 4th line to `"name": "python3"`, it will work in the test environment.

But I'm sure there must be a better way.  Is there a way to save a jupyter notebook that will run on anyone's machine i.e. with no information on the local environment?

Comment: The reason the kernel information is required is coz the notebook _may have_ features dependent on the kernel. Imagine if you were using Python2 and then you stripped of that info and someone tried to run your notebook on Python3. (Yes, there may be 3.x vs 3.y issues too, even if it's just Python3.) I'd recommend a [commit-hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_client_side_hooks) to modify that line via a script, which executes when you commit.

Comment: It's true the notebook can't be run without the correct environment/kernel. But I would argue the name of the kernel is not important. It could be `'control-dev'`, `'python3'` or `'timbuktoo'`.  What's important is that the dependencies are correct not the name!

Comment: A commit-hook seems like a good solution. I suppose a client-side hook would be best in this case where  numerous people might be editing and merging the notebooks and not using the same kernel naming conventions.